# Save value of textarea in database Mysql

Tags: mysql, textarea

when I record the textarea value in the MySQL database, I notice the addition of a character between spaces 'Â' last this turns into '&nbsp' when I display my text in label, Please enyone give me an explanation for this behavior!!!!

Comment: You've got a character set issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: thanks my friend it works prefctely (y)